# Converting trip durations to parking durations

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data of trip durations of few hundred thousand people, what I wanna do is to convert the table of trip durations to parking durations for each person in the new dataframe as showed in the picture. Is there possible way to do in R? It could be easy, but since I am new in R, I am struggling a lot. Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you convert your times to `POSIXct` it will add dates, though these could be removed before providing the final result.

This approach is not necessarily the fastest but may work for you. The rows added are dependent on previous `end_time` and the following row `start_time`.

It adds midnight before and after your data for each `ID` to include time intervals with midnight.

```
library(dplyr)

result <- data.frame(ID = as.numeric(),
                     start = as.POSIXct(character()),
                     end = as.POSIXct(character()))

df$start_time <- as.POSIXct(df$start_time, format = "%H:%M")
df$end_time <- as.POSIXct(df$end_time, format = "%H:%M")

first_time <- as.POSIXct("00:00", format = "%H:%M")
last_time <- as.POSIXct("24:00", format = "%H:%M")

for (i in unique(df$ID)) {
  sub_i <- bind_rows(
    data.frame(ID = i, start_time = first_time, end_time = first_time),
    subset(df, ID == i),
    data.frame(ID = i, start_time = last_time, end_time = last_time)
  )
  adding <- data.frame(ID = i, start = sub_i$end_time[-nrow(sub_i)], end = sub_i$start[-1])
  adding <- adding[adding$start <= adding$end, ]
  result <- bind_rows(result, adding)
}

result$start <- format(result$start, "%H:%M")
result$end <- format(result$end, "%H:%M")

result[order(result$ID, result$start), c("ID", "start", "end")]
```

**Output**

```
    ID start   end
1 2353 00:00 06:00
2 2353 06:30 11:20
3 2353 12:00 16:00
4 2353 16:30 00:00
5 3232 00:00 07:00
6 3232 07:45 18:00
7 3232 18:45 00:00
```

**Data**

```
df <- data.frame(
  ID = c(2353,2353,2353,3232,3232),
  start_time = c("6:00", "11:20", "16:00", "7:00", "18:00"),
  end_time = c("6:30", "12:00", "16:30", "7:45", "18:45")
)
```

**Edit**:

Will leave in the old code for now until we can confirm this works.

I'm not sure what you are using to read the Excel file, but here I used `readxl`.

Upon reading the file, it already is in `POSIXct` format, so I commented out those lines. The date is origin of 1899-12-31. I added `UTC` time zone to be consistent here.

Let me know if this works.

```
library(dplyr)
library(readxl)

df <- readxl::read_xlsx("pkw_r_R.xlsx")

# df <- data.frame(
#   ID = c(2353,2353,2353,3232,3232,4100),
#   start_time = c("6:00", "11:20", "16:00", "7:00", "18:00", "05:00"),
#   end_time = c("6:30", "12:00", "16:30", "7:45", "18:45", "00:00")
# )

result <- data.frame(hp_id = as.numeric(),
                     start = as.POSIXct(character()),
                     end = as.POSIXct(character()))

# df$start_time <- as.POSIXct(df$start_time, format = "%H:%M")
# df$end_time <- as.POSIXct(df$end_time, format = "%H:%M")

first_time <- as.POSIXct("1899-12-31 00:00", format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M", tz = "UTC")
last_time <- as.POSIXct("1899-12-31 24:00", format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M", tz = "UTC")

for (i in unique(df$hp_id)) {
  sub_i <- bind_rows(
    data.frame(hp_id = i, st_time = first_time, end_time = first_time),
    subset(df, hp_id == i),
    data.frame(hp_id = i, st_time = last_time, end_time = last_time)
  )
  print(i)
  adding <- data.frame(hp_id = i, start = sub_i$end_time[-nrow(sub_i)], end = sub_i$st_time[-1])
  adding <- adding[adding$start <= adding$end, ]
  result <- bind_rows(result, adding)
}

result$start <- format(result$start, "%H:%M")
result$end <- format(result$end, "%H:%M")

result[order(result$hp_id, result$start), c("hp_id", "start", "end")]
```